# Javascript - Numbers showing as NaN and object undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a comment generator for a program we use, and I am having an issue with numbers. I originally got `object undefined` after doing the math when I used the block of code below:

```js
totalPages = toString(totalPages);
pagesLeft = toString(pagesLeft);
pph = toString(pph);
hour = toString(hour);
minute = toString(minute);
weekTG = toString(weekTG);
```

Then, I tried using the `Number` function when I got the values from the HTML inputs:

```
var totalPages = document.getElementById("totalPages");
var startPage = document.getElementById("startPage");
var endPage = document.getElementById("endPage");
totalPages = Number(totalPages);
startPage = Number(startPage);
endPage = Number(endPage);
```

When I used the above method, I got `NaN`. I also tried using `parseFloat` but that did not work out. Could I have some help? If you would like to look at my code further, you can look [here](https://repl.it/@launcherman08/CommentCreator) in `script.js`.
The output is currently in the console, just to clear up any future confusion.

Comment: NaN occurs when you are trying to preform a mathematical operation on a non-number value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`totalPages`, `startPage` and `endPage` are the elements themselves, you have to take the `value` (if element is input) or `textContent` (if element is other than input) from them:

```
var totalPages = document.getElementById("totalPages").value;
var startPage = document.getElementById("startPage").value;
var endPage = document.getElementById("endPage").value;
```

Comment: Thank you! That did help with the console.log. EDIT: Thank you again, the console.log was just me testing the output. I now put it out to innerHTML, big thanks!

Comment: @Mamum, thanks again for the ```textContext``` reference because that answers a question about copying and pasting I had.